# How can I copy a rows' values into new row datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I have a datagridview with 5 columns.
For each new rowadded I want to copy the last rows' values into the new one except for one.
can anyone help me pls?

I'm a bit new to c# :/

I've been trying something like this

```
       foreach (DataGridViewColumn Column in dataGridView1.Columns)
       {
           foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                   if (cell.RowIndex != lastrowindex)
                   {
                       if (cell.FormattedValue == String.Empty)
                       {
                           listNames.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                       }
                   }
            }
       }
       string strNames = null;
       foreach (string name in listNames)
           strNames += name + Environment.NewLine;
       MessageBox.Show("List of all rows\n\n" + strNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
if (cell.FormattedValue == String.Empty)
{
    listNames.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
}
```

I can imagine that if `FormattedValue` is empty, than cell.Value.ToString() is also empty. If so... your collection `listNames` is filled with empty strings result in strNames which exists only of newlines...

Perhaps you want to change `==` into `!=`:

```
if (cell.FormattedValue != String.Empty)
{
    listNames.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
}
```